# proxing everything with Haproxy

Tags: proxy, haproxy

is it possible to not define backend in Haproxy configuration to make a proxy for every TCP connection? So if I will try to connect from host A(sftp,ssh,smtp) through HAproxy it will always reach destination.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a method to "proxyfy" all TCP connections in HAProxy.

You should set up a front end and bind it to multiple ports, like:

```
bind 0.0.0.0:21
bind 0.0.0.0:22
bind 0.0.0.0:25
```

Then, based on port, set an ACL and a backend to that ACL, for every interesting port/service:

```
acl is_ftp dst_port 21
acl is_ssh dst_port 22
acl is_smtp dst_port 25

use_backend ssh if is_ftp
use_backend ftp if is_ssh
use_backend smtp if is_smtp
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstand the question but if you dont define the ports on the frontend and the backend - then all traffic will stay on its current port i.e. WEB 80 -> 80 & SMTP 25 -> 25

```
listen L7_TCP_ALLPORTS
bind 10.0.0.20
mode tcp 
balance leastconn 
server RS001 192.168.1.21 check port 80
```

*NB. You will need to specify the check port(otherwise it wont know).*

Comment: it doesn't work